# Enviar dados JSON de Javascript para PHP

Tags: php, javascript, json

Estou tentando enviar dados no formato json do javascript para o php conforme códigos abaixo. Porém o resultado de var_dump($_dados) é sempre NULL. Testei o array atividade do javascript e o mesmo está ok, com os dados que deveria estar.

Javascript:

```
var gravaDados = function(){
     $.ajax({
          url : "./php/xml-request.php",
          type : 'post',
          data : {
            set_optx : "",
            dados : (JSON.stringify(atividades)),
            regiao :'Itabira'
          }
     })
     .done(function(msg){
          alert(msg);
     })
     .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, msg){
          alert(msg);
     }); 
}
```

PHP:

```
    if(isset($_POST['set_optx'])){

        $_dados = json_decode($_POST['dados']);
        $_regiao = $_POST['regiao'];

        var_dump($_dados);
        // Receberá todos os dados do XML
        $xml = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='ISO-8859-1'?>\n";

        $xml.= "<regiao>".$_regiao."</regiao>\n";

        // A raiz do meu documento XML
        $xml .= "<atividades>\n";

        for ( $i = 0; $i < count( $_dados ); $i++ ) {
            $xml .= "\t<atividade>\n";
            $xml .= "\t\t<prefixo>" . $_dados[$i]->{"prefixo"} . "</prefixo>\n";
            $xml .= "\t\t<local_troca>" . $_dados[$i]->{"local_troca"} . "</local_troca>\n";
            $xml .= "\t\t<horario>" . $_dados[$i]->{"horario"} . "</horario>\n";
            $xml .= "\t\t<veiculo>" . $_dados[$i]->{"veiculo"} . "</veiculo>\n";
            $xml .= "\t\t<atividade>" . $_dados[$i]->{"atividade"} . "</atividade>\n";
            $xml .= "\t\t<matricula>" . $_dados[$i]->{"matricula"} . "</matricula>\n";
            $xml .= "\t\t<nome>" . $_dados[$i]->{"nome"} . "</nome>\n";
            $xml .= "\t</atividade>\n";
        }

        $xml .= "</atividades>\n";

        // Escreve o arquivo
        $fp = fopen('_dados.xml', 'w+');
        fwrite($fp, $xml);
        fclose($fp);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

No AJAX passa os dados direto, em `dados : (JSON.stringify(atividades)),` tira o `JSON.stringify` assim, `dados : atividades,`

e no PHP não precisa do `json_decode`, coloca um `var_dump($_POST)` para verificar.

Se quiser garantir que a comunicação seja feita através de JSON coloca depois do `type`:

`dataType: 'JSON',`

assim, se não existir uma resposta JSON do back-end o AJAX acusa erro

Comment: Funcionou sem o dataType, porém está enviando como array e não json.

Comment: O `dataType` garante que a resposta seja JSON e se não for da erro, mas o envio não. Experimenta colocar `console.log(JSON.stringify(atividades));` para validar se o valor esta correto. E porque o envio dos dados tem que ser JSON as outras informações não?

Answer (score 0):

## Use a função json_encode para apresentar o json.

Exemplo:

```
$fruta[1] = 'Laranja';
$fruta[2] = 'Banana';
$fruta[3] = 'Abacate';

echo json_encode($fruta);
```

Resultado:

> {"1":"Laranja","2":"Banana","3":"Abacate"}